# How can I report the advanced networking configuration as plain text?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line

What command can I use to get all these settings (and their values) into a text file?

I can locate them in the registry but can't get their selected values...  This is just how I can ask people having network problems to report those details (it would be good to have the information available).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Microsoft's official **DevCon** tool, which can be run by the command line.  From Microsoft's website, they describe it as:

> The DevCon command-line utility is as an alternative to Device Manager.

[You can get the tool **here**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272), along with the basic documentation.  It's a very robust tool, and with a bit of tweaking and command line switches, should do exactly what you need.

You can use the `>` operator to stream the output from stdout to a file (e.g. `devcon [args] > output.txt`).  You can then wrap everything into a batchfile and distribute it to your users.

Comment: Hrm... You really do like using that <h1> tag don't you ;)

Comment: (I dislike that heading stuff a lot to be honest.)

Comment: thanks Breakthrough, but Im looking to do it by windows defaults tools. and no need for a highlight anyway

Comment: @Breakthrough, looks much better to me, thanks. (And in the previous revision with the heading, I didn't even realise this was some quote!)

Comment: @Revolter, just in case it matters to you: this DevCon tool may not be built-in to Windows, but it actually *is* a Microsoft-provided download.

Comment: @ the first two:  If people's posts bother you too much, just change the styling with a Firefox addon. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use netsh command to check/modify such network interface settings. Some examples can be found here:
[Netsh commands for interface IP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx) 
[Manage Windows Network settings with netsh](http://www.winplanet.com/article/4394-.htm) 
[Configure TCP/IP from command line](http://www.petri.co.il/configure_tcp_ip_from_cmd.htm)

Comment: this doesn't help too much

Comment: No, you can't. These are NIC-specific settings, netsh only allows you to poke around in Windows's network settings.

Answer (score 0):

I use CIM and Powershell for this:

```
(
Get-CIMInstance CIM_NetworkAdapter | 
  Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Network adapter name"} | 
    Select-Object * -Exclude Cim* | 
      Out-String
) >"Text file path"
```